# Enterprise architect : C# add-in current selected item tagged value

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I have own profile in EA and i can give a own note element with a specific tag value. My problem is, that i want select some note in project and change tag value through add-in. How can i get current selected element ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Repository.GetContextObject()
```

to get the currently selected Object.
To get the type of the object, use `Repository.GetContextItemType()`

you can then assign an `EA.Element` type to the object returned by  `Repository.GetContextObject()`

```
 private void getSelectedElement(EA.Repository Rep)
            {
                EA.Element ele;
                switch(Rep.GetContextItemType())
                {
                    case EA.ObjectType.otElement:
                        {
                            ele = Rep.GetContextObject();
                            //Operations on the selected element
                            break;
                        }
                } 
            }
```

If you want to know all the possible types,
see the [documentation](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/objecttypeenum.html) (This is for EA 13)

Answer (score 2):

RTM: `Respository.GetTreeSelectedObject`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15647274)

Comment: It doesnt give me element but object only. I need element, because i need change tag value.

Comment: Well, the object IS the element. The tags are in the Element.TaggedValues collection.

Comment: @Psi Well, actually it DOES give an answer. The question is either too basic of not elaborated well. Let's see,

Comment: Respository.GetTreeSelectedObject will give you the item selected in the project Browser

Comment: @MartinGrégoire Depends on how you interpret the OP's question "get current selected element"

Comment: @ThomasKilian In this case he's looking for a note, which you will never get in the Project Browser

Comment: @ThomasKilian but it gives me this `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'EA.Element'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface `

Comment: @MartinGrégoire that is what i need :)

Comment: @pepo, see my replies with Thomas. He gave you the code for an element selected in the project browser, which in this case, on the screenshot, what is selected is a diagram. When trying to assign an EA.Element to an object which is actually a Diagram, it will give you this error

Answer (score -1):

I use this function (VBScript).
It combines answers from *Mart10* and *qwerty_so*:

```
function getSelectedElement() ' as EA.Element
    
    dim sel
    
    set sel = Repository.GetContextObject
    if sel is nothing then sel = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject()
    
    if sel.ObjectType <> otElement then set sel = nothing
    
    set getSelectedElement= sel
end function
```

Primarily it looks for the active Diagram's selection and secondarily in the Project Browser, finally filters for `EA.Element`-s .

**NOTE:** The purpose of method `GetContextItemType()` is not obvious to me, as each Object knows it's type by property `ObjectType`.